# std::vector segv because of an improbable corruption

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have a segmentation fault in the following code ( on `_answers.push_back(tmp);` ).

Gdb said

```
(gdb) p tmp
$7 = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nSet-Cookie: color=black;path=/\r\nSet-Cookie: code=f69a2d941420d23be97bbb1ae963295647a91c4f3faf9c5fa80727399927d9d5;path=/\r\nSet-Cookie: game=c1e"...
(gdb) call _answers.size()
$8 = 271275648142580811
```

So I guess the array has been corrupted. But I don't know where it happened.

```
// Network.hpp
#pragma once

#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class Network
{
  public:
    Network(std::string const &, std::string const &);
    ~Network() {};

    void init();
    void connect();
    void update();
    void sendQuery(const std::string);
    bool isConnected();
    void reset();

    std::string getAnswer();

    void handleRead(const boost::system::error_code &, size_t);
    void handleWrite(const boost::system::error_code &);

    boost::asio::io_service _io_service;

  private:
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver _resolver;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _sock;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator _it;
    char _buff[2048];
    std::vector<std::string> _answers;
    std::string const &_host;
    std::string const &_port;
    bool _answered;
};

// Network.cpp
Network::Network(std::string const &host, std::string const &port) : _resolver(_io_service), _sock(_io_service), _host(host), _port(port), _answered(true) {}

void Network::connect() {
  _answers.reserve(2048);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(_host, _port);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = _resolver.resolve(query);
  boost::asio::connect(_sock.lowest_layer(), iterator);
}

void Network::handleRead(const boost::system::error_code &err, size_t bread) {
  _answered = true;
  if (err && err.value() != 2)
    throw Gomoku::NetworkException(err.message());
  if (bread > 0) {
    std::string tmp(_buff);
    _answers.push_back(tmp);
  }
  memset(_buff, 0, 2048);
}

void Network::handleWrite(const boost::system::error_code &err) {
  if (err)
    throw Gomoku::NetworkException(err.message());
}

void Network::reset() {
  _io_service.poll();
  _io_service.reset();
  _answers.clear();
  _answered = true;
}

void Network::sendQuery(const std::string req) {
  _io_service.poll();
  _io_service.reset();
  if (_answered == 0)
    return;
  _answered = false;
  connect();
  const char *str = new char[req.length()];
  str = req.c_str();
  boost::asio::async_write(_sock, boost::asio::buffer(str, req.length()), boost::bind(&Network::handleWrite, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  boost::asio::async_read(_sock, boost::asio::buffer(_buff, 2048), boost::bind(&Network::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

std::string Network::getAnswer() {
  if (_answers.empty())
    return "";
  std::string tmp = _answers.back();
  _answers.pop_back();
  return tmp;
}

// Player.cpp
Player::Player(std::string const &host, std::string const &port) : _network(host, port) {
  _myTurn = false;
  _whiteScore = _blackScore = 0;
  _host = host + ":" + port;
  initMap();
}

void Player::connect() {
  std::string str = "GET /players/connect/ HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: " + _host + "\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n";
  _network.sendQuery(str);
}

void Player::sendClick(std::pair<int, int> click, std::string const &header) {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "POST /game/play/" << click.first << "/" << click.second << header << _cookie << "\r\n\r\n";
  std::string req = ss.str();
  _network.sendQuery(req);
  _network._io_service.run();
  _network._io_service.reset();
  std::string ans = _network.getAnswer();
  parseAnswer(ans);
  req = "GET /game/map.txt" + header + _cookie + "\r\n\r\n";
  _network.sendQuery(req);
}
```

I also saw the following code by following the segv trace (basic_string.h:400):

```
: _M_dataplus(_M_local_data(), __str._M_get_allocator()) // TODO A traits
```

Comment: Your error might have to do with `std::string tmp(_buff); _answers.push_back(tmp);`, but conveniently, you didn't show us how that variable was declared or initialized. Please include a complete, minimal, compilable example that exhibits this bug.

Comment: `const char *str = new char[req.length()];  str = req.c_str();` This is a memory leak.  In addition `req` is a by-value parameter, thus is basically a local variable.  It goes out of scope as soon as that function returns.

Comment: The complete minimal example I have take 4 files.
But anyway, _buff is a valid char[2048] with it's \0 at the end and is only manipulated by
```boost::asio::async_read(_sock, boost::asio::buffer(_buff, 2048), boost::bind(&Network::handleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));```

Same thing for _answers, witch is a simple std::vector<std::string>, only manipulated in this file.

all the variables with "_XXX" are instance variables declared in the header

Comment: Your latest edit does not show where, when, and how that `Network` instance is created or used.   You could have a bogus `Network` instance being used, thus the vector member within it is garbage.

Comment: You need to post a complete reproducing example. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance: `std::string tmp(_buff);` is wrong, because `_buff` may not be null terminated, thus reading 271275648142580811 bytes into memory.

Additionally, sendQuery's parameter is a local string, so as soon as the function exits, the string is free'd, and async_write continues to read from invalid memory, which is undefined behavior. Anything can happen.

Also, all requests use the same incoming buffer, so if multiple occur at the same time, you get undefined or useless behavior.

Comment: _buff is null terminated (checked via gdb).

Comment: No, _buf is _usually_ null terminated. But not always.

Comment: @Arthur Unless you address the issue of the memory leak and local variable usage, both pointed out to you by the answer above and my comment, anything else you encounter is moot.